# Frozen outdoor spigot, small leak from indoor shut off valve

Tags: leak, faucet, plumbing-fixture

So I shut off the indoor valve to my outdoor spigot and then opened the outdoor valve to drain in the fall. There was a slight drip like the indoor valve wasn't closing all the way but then it stopped. After I returned from vacation apparently the drip returned and now the outdoor spigot is frozen. I went down stairs and there is some ice formed on the framing and there is a very slow drip. Can't tell if the pipe has split. We are in single digits at this point. So my question is should I be worried about further damage? The indoor valve will still have a slight leak but if the piping to the exterior already split do I need to worry? And if it hasn't split what can it do to avoid it? Thanks